# REACT component can work with onClink event

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sass

I'm new in REACT, I'm trying to make a slider, so I need this `<img>` to act like a button, I tried to use an onClick event to test the functionality by sending a simple console.log, but it does nothing at all!, I really can´t find the problem, it sends no error, it just didn't work.
I have another `<img>` with an onClick event that works just fine, in another component, so I can't tell what's the problem here.
Also, I thought maybe was my console.log so I call an Alert, but no, that didn't work either. Could anyone help me?

The code looks something like this:

```
const  SliderInstructors = () => {
 const siguiente = () => {
        console.log('Siguiente');
        alert('You clicked me!');
    };

    const anterior = () => {
        console.log('Anterior');
        alert('You clicked me!');
    };

    

    return(
        <>   {/* Controles */}
                <div className="controls">
                    <img onClick={() => anterior} src={ArrowLeft} style={{'pointer-events': "all"}} alt="Before"/>
                    <img onClick={() => siguiente} src={ArrowRight} style={{'pointer-events': "all"}} alt="After"/>
                </div>
        </>
    )
}


export default SliderInstructors;
```

This is a component which I send to call to a Page, like this

```
import SliderInstructors from '../components/SliderInstructors';



function AboutUs() {

    const { t} = useTranslation();
    return (
        <><div className="instructorsAbout">
                   <h2>{t('about.instructor')}</h2>
                   <div className="infoInstructors">
                        <SliderInstructors/>
                   </div>
           </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default AboutUs;
```

I thought maybe was my styles but I deleted the styles from them component and nothing, also I tried to put the component directly in the App.js but nop, so I really don't know where to keep looking at.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <img onClick={() => anterior()} src={ArrowLeft} style={{'pointer-events': "all"}} alt="Before"/>
                <img onClick={() => siguiente()} src={ArrowRight} style={{'pointer-events': "all"}} alt="After"/>
```

or

```
  <img onClick={anterior} src={ArrowLeft} style={{'pointer-events': "all"}} alt="Before"/>
                <img onClick={ siguiente} src={ArrowRight} style={{'pointer-events': "all"}} alt="After"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! this works, also I remove all the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the anterior and siguiente functions without anonymous functions on onClick.

```
<img onClick={anterior} src={ArrowLeft} style={{'pointer-events': "all"}} alt="Before"/>
```

```
<img onClick={siguiente} src={ArrowRight} style={{'pointer-events': "all"}} alt="After"/>
```